# bash cleanup with RETURN trap and resetting handler immediately

Tags: bash, bash-trap

Is there a way to disable a trap within the trap handler?

I'd like to simplify some code by using the RETURN trap. my_func will return the value of my_command. The tmpfile will be cleaned up  as my_func returns. This technique would allow me to avoid assigning a temp var to hold $? from my_func while I do cleanup.

However, I'm unable to reset the trap handler within the handler and cleanup is now invoked after every function return.

Ultimately what I really want to do is cleanup after my_command is invoked but still have it as the last command so the return value is implicit. Any suggested alternatives would be appreciated.

```
cleanup() { # generic cleanup w/ reset
   "$@"
   trap - RETURN
}

my_func() {
   local -r tmpfile="/tmp/tmpfile"
   trap "cleanup rm ${tmpfile}" RETURN
   my_command -f ${tmpfile}
}

caller() {
   if my_func ; then
      do_success_ops
   fi
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a Bash-specific issue; in Zsh for example, you can reset the trap in trap handler. I use this trick to recover `INT` traps. (`RETURN` is called `EXIT` in Zsh, and it’s *local*, so you don’t even need to clean-up the trap itself.)

Answer (score 1):

I always use this pattern:

```
trap 'rm -rf "$workspace"' EXIT
workspace="$(mktemp --directory)" # Or -d
# Use $workspace
```

This has several nice features:

1. The trap is set up *before* creating the directory, so there is no race condition.
2. Creating a directory means I shouldn't need any more `mktemp` calls in the script, because I can just put everything in that directory.
3. Creating a directory rather than a file gives a better security baseline, because it's common that everyone can see what's directly in `/tmp`, but a new directory will be owned by you and will be created "u+rwx, minus umask restrictions" (from `man mktemp`).

If you want to clean up *earlier* I would recommend just doing it explicitly. Your solution has two unnecessary levels of indirection: the trap and the passing of arguments to be run.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do, in fact, use this temp directory pattern already, it is very useful.

The example is just a simple excerpt of a much larger script. The cleanup function is intended to run anything (and maybe do much more than just removing a file). For example, at times I need to clear the screen (but I don't want the screen cleared after every function exit). The essence of my question is if there is something akin to a finally block in Java. Please don't be concerned about what the cleanup code is actually doing.